# increase the cost of query after partition the DB

Tags: performance, oracle11g, database-partitioning, sql-tuning

i have a query with high cost , and this cost appear after i partition my db . i don't know what make this problem . partition is on date.

the query is :

```
update EBSESSIONSERVICE set RESPONSETIME=:1 , DURATION=:2  where ID=:3  and REQUESTTIME>sysdate-:4
```

and EBSESSIONSERVICE Table is :

```
create table EBSESSIONSERVICE (   id                NUMBER(19) not null,   description       VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),   requesttime       TIMESTAMP(6) not null,   responsetime      TIMESTAMP(6),   serviceid   NUMBER(19),   failurereasonid   NUMBER(19),   sessionid         NUMBER(19),   duration          NUMBER(19),   error_code        VARCHAR2(50),   requested_amount  NUMBER(19,2),   applied_amount    NUMBER(19,2),   sub_service_id    VARCHAR2(50),   sub_service_title VARCHAR2(100),   instance_number   NUMBER(19),   sub_system_type   NUMBER(2),   currency          VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) ) partition by range (REQUESTTIME) (   partition P1 values less than (TIMESTAMP' 2010-01-21 00:00:00')
tablespace PERF
pctfree 10
initrans 1
maxtrans 255
storage
(
  initial 8M
  next 1M
  minextents 1
  maxextents unlimited
),   partition SYS_P27331 values less than (TIMESTAMP' 2010-12-15 00:00:00')
tablespace PERF
pctfree 10
initrans 1
maxtrans 255
storage
(
  initial 8M
  next 1M
  minextents 1
  maxextents unlimited
),

. 
. 
.
.
.

-- Create/Recreate indexes 
create index IDX_SS_AMOUNT on EBSESSIONSERVICE (REQUESTED_AMOUNT)
  local;
create index IDX_SS_REQUESTTIME on EBSESSIONSERVICE (REQUESTTIME)
  local;
create index IDX_SS_SERVICEID on EBSESSIONSERVICE (SERVICEID)
  local;
create index IDX_SS_SESSIONID on EBSESSIONSERVICE (SESSIONID)
  local;
create index SYS_C0  0100184 on EBSESSIONSERVICE (ID)
  local;
```

when i set 3-4 for sysdate the cost is normal, but when i use sysdate about 60 , the cost increase to 1400 . sysdate is the maximum value of a set , and in this scenario it is about one day so the condition in where clause include just 1 or 2 portition. why the cost of this query is so high?

Comment: Does the query actually run slowly?  Or are you just concerned about the numeric cost?  If the query does run slowly, what is the query plan?  It sounds like you are saying that the cost goes up if your predicate changes from `sysdate-4` to `sysdate-60` which makes sense.  If that's your predicate, how would Oracle know that it only has to scan one or two partitions?

Comment: @JustinCave , when i partition my DB , the cpu usage of DB increase from 30% to 95% . i try to found out which query use the cpu . the cpu usage of the queries on this table (update and insert) is much more than the previous db (not partition) . and then i see the cost of the update query and found the cost of the query is high. i delete the condition in where clause and see the cost is 1 and when use that condition the cost increase to 1443 , while i use this condition to help the oracle find the appropriate partition .

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that the query runs longer if your predicate changes from `sysdate-4` to `sysdate-60` which makes sense. If that's your predicate, how would Oracle know that it only has to scan one or two partitions?  Partitioning a table is not a magic "go faster" option.  If you have to scan 60 local indexes on a partitioned table, that's going to be a lot more expensive that scanning one slightly larger index on a non-partitioned table.

Comment: @JustinCave i am beginner in DB concepts. i explain the scenario , please help me to solve my problem . at first the DB was not partitioned , we need to have some report from DB (select statement) and it run so slowly , to solve this problem i partition the DB, and the problem solve and select statement run fast. but the cpu usage in other scenario increase highly . and i found the update and insert on that table use the cpu such high. how can i manage the indexes to reduce this cpu usage?

Comment: You may not be able to--  this may be a trade-off.  You may want to create a global index on `id, requesttime`.  But that will create issues for some types of load operations.  I'm generally not a fan of global indexes on partitioned tables.  Anything you do with partitioning is likely to have trade-offs.  Since we have no insight into your system or what trade-offs you want to make, it's very hard to guess at what trade-offs might be acceptable to you.

Comment: @JustinCave thank you so much

Comment: @JustinCave , i have another question. i have two index , on id and on requesttime, in my query(you can see it above) when i set requesttime<sys date-100 , the oracle use request time index and the cost is good, but when i use requesttime<sys date-200 the oracle use ID index and the cost increase highly. as i said my partitioning is on requesttime.  why oracle do this?